# Hashnot matching generated from solidity contract and web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design, abi, hash-algorithm

I want to make hash same as generating by solidity contract from web3 or ether's js.

In solidity contract hash generation by below :
sha256(abi.encodePacked(**no of parameters**)).

Kindly help for it. how can i generate using web3 or ether's js same hash.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: ok. Here i share what i perform to get it.

I have solidity contract which has function for generate hash as below :

hash = sha256(abi.encodePacked(address(this),existingValuation,ValuationBased,ApprovedFunding,AmountForSpendingOutside));
                                        
hash from solidity : 0xbf9445cd5490b7d06a4986b0591d84eee666cebc1fb68b72f0bbfbfe528b5763

Comment: I have javascript code which has function for generate hash as below :

var Operationhash = abiLib.soliditySHA3(['address', 'uint', 'bool', 'uint','uint'],[new BN(request.body.contract_address.replace('0x', ''), 16),existingValuation,ValuationBased,ApprovedFunding,AmountForSpendingOutside]);
   
hash = '0x' + Buffer.concat([Operationhash]).toString('hex');

hash from code : 0x06c30e714b1ad43ea087953f5ce9d46c1869e316c4ae21b4b80ab7bbcd80bfc9

Comment: here both has become different for same input value.

Comment: Your Solidity code is using `sha256`, but your JavaScript code is using `keccak256`. Those are two completely different hash algorithms. Try changing your Solidity code to use `hash = keccak256(...)` instead.

Comment: I updated solidity code with keccak256 still got different hash from contract and javascript code.

Answer (score 5):

In solidity the hash is generated using:

```
function generateHash(param1, param2, ... paramN) public pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(param1, param2, ... paramN));
}
```

In web3.js v1.2.6, the same hash can be generated using:

```
web3.utils.soliditySha3(param1, param2, ... paramN);
Example:
  > const web3 = require('web3');
  > web3.utils.soliditySha3('balaji', 10000);
  > '0x6d4e07169abf3d9047d7d5283460790fe3f80395521c9a376768679fc27b4687'
```

In ethers.js the same hash can be generated using:

```
ethers.utils.soliditySha3(['paramTypes'], ['paramValues'])

Example:
  > const ethers = require('ethers');
  > > ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['string', 'uint256'], ['balaji', 10000]);
  > '0x6d4e07169abf3d9047d7d5283460790fe3f80395521c9a376768679fc27b4687'
```

Answer (score 0):

*In my opinion*, this is a case where it is worthwhile for a contract to present a "helper" function that will ensure that clients can easily match the contract's hash process. I think it's important to ensure they can do so regardless of the language, *and will always be able to do so in the future*.

The pattern is simple. Whatever the contract is doing, code it as a `public pure` function. Use it internally.

This ensures external clients will always be able to match the contract's internal logic.

```
function hashHelper(address a, bytes32 b, uint c) public pure returns(bytes32) {
  return ... // keccak256(..., sha3( ..., whatever
}

function commit(bytes32 hash) public pure {
  // record committment
}

function reveal (address a, bytes32 b, uint c) public {
  require(hashHelper(a,b,c) == hash, "Invalid Hash inputs");
}
```

When clients call the `pure` function, it's the same as them running a hash computation locally and nothing confidential is revealed to the network.

Hope it helps.